# While running a long OpsHub TFS Migration how does it know when new changesets have been added?

Tags: tfs, opshub, tfs-migration

We are running a long migration and our developers are using the onprem TFS while the migration is working.   In the documentation I see this:

Note: Your source TFS usage is not required to be frozen or put on-hold for the migration. The migration utility can run perfectly fine in the background, and so your team can continue using TFS while the migration is running

Can you tell me how the tool knows about new changesets that have happened during the migration process ?   So once it completes do we need to re-run it to grab these ?

Comment: Migration happens sequentially, so whilst the migration is running the delta appends itself at the end like an item in a queue. So, when the migration is complete the delta too is then sequentially processed and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is running it's just iterating through all changesets from the first to the last, keeping track of which have been processed and which haven't. While you're working (as long as you don't do destructive things, like `tf destroy`), it will just keep iterating and will probably end up on 8421/8400 at the end (the 21 are the changesets that were added while the migration was running).

Even when the migration finishes and you decide not to jump over directly, you'll be able to restart (only available in the commercial edition of OpsHub) which will continue where the migration left off. Just make sure you keep the original migration records and restart the migration that finished previously. if you start a new migration to "catch up" it'll compare all changesets between source and target again.

Comment: Thanks for that - we did do some cleanup using tf destroy for branches that were deleted in VS but not destroyed thinking that this was why it was taking so long.   Do you know if this will impact the migration ?

Comment: I don't know. OpsHub has a couple of not very well documented behaviors for situations where the source branch or target branch doesn't exist anymore. OpsHub support may know.

Comment: Do you remember whether the '/keephistory' flag was enabled or disabled for destroy command? In case no trace of that item(s) exist (ie. /keephistory was disabled) then there will be no problems